# IBM Cloud Kubernetes - Cannot get a new refresh token

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud

I am trying to access my cluster (running for example `kubectl get pods`) and I'm getting an error response with this:

> "errorMessage":"Provided refresh token is expired"

[This documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_cli_install.html#cs_cli_refresh) says that you are provided a new refresh token when you run the `export KUBECONFIG=....` command to get your cluster configuration, which I have done mulitple times now. Is there something else I can do to get a new refresh token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you ran `ibmcloud ks cluster-config <cluster_name>` again first to get the new config download before you ran `export KUBECONFIG`?

I'd also try logging out/logging in again and making sure you're targeting the correct region with `ibmcloud target`

Comment: Running `ibmcloud ks cluster-config <cluster_name>` did it. I grabbed the new export command from that and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: For me it was `ic ks cluster config --cluster <cluster_name>`